# Localizing the API response in Custom Police Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have implemented localization in Azure ADB2C custom policy.

```
<ClaimType Id="signInName">
    <DisplayName>Please enter your email</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Enter your email address to signin</UserHelpText>
    <Restriction>
        <Pattern RegularExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"/>
    </Restriction>
</ClaimType>

<Localization Enabled="true">
    <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
        <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
        <SupportedLanguage>es</SupportedLanguage>
    </SupportedLanguages>
    <LocalizedResources Id="en">
        <LocalizedStrings>
            <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Please enter your email</LocalizedString>
            <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="UserHelpText">Enter your email address to signin</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
    <LocalizedResources Id="es">
        <LocalizedStrings>
            <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="DisplayName">Por favor introduzca su correo electrónico</LocalizedString>
            <LocalizedString ElementType="ClaimType" ElementId="signInName" StringId="UserHelpText">Ingrese su dirección de correo electrónico para iniciar sesión</LocalizedString>
        </LocalizedStrings>
    </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

Everything is working as expected but when the login button is clicked, an API call is made and the response is always in English. Also the query string parameter to indicate the language is not sent in the API call. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: is that message coming from a custom validation technical profile or the default one (the AAD one who checks credentials)?

Comment: Hi @Baloon1985 How are you passing the language parameter? Can you paste the REST API technical profile in the above question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first find what is the string ID which is showing this error.

We support [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-or-sign-in-page-elements) IDs for localization which you might have customized in your policies.

Then, once you know which ID is being used for your error message, you can add a `LocalizedString` element like below (For example, I am assuming the `ElementType` is `ErrorMessage` and `StringID` is `DefaultMessage`):

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="DefaultMessage">#Invalid username or password.</LocalizedString>
```

You can find out different examples of the same here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization

Comment: There is no string Id. How do I get it or configure it? This error message is from IEF.

<div class="error pageLevel" aria-hidden="false" role="alert" style="display: block;">
 <p>The username or password provided in the request are invalid.</p>
</div>